# How to check if the tape starts with special characters

Tags: c#, string, character

I need to track to string began with the required letters (Cyrillic or Latin or even any letters). But definitely not with numbers or special characters including space.

For start my task was only hanlde string starts with number but for now also certain characters.

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        if (isRoot && (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out i)))
```

What should I do for characters?? Use something like this (but in this case I need to make conditions for all characters):

```
(textBox1.Text.Trim(). StartsWith("%") || textBox1.Text.Trim().StartsWith("-") || ...... 
)
```

Is there some better ways?? Coz if you propose to allow only letters then it is a bad idea because it can be given a different language.. So what?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression to handle this functionality.
For example:
This snippet makes sure an input file path is correctly formatted.

```
// [drive_letter]:\ or  \\[server]\ or [drive name]:\
private const string PathPattern = "^[A-z]:[\\\\/]|^\\\\|^.*[A-z]:[\\\\/]";
var matchMaker = new Regex(PathPattern);
var success = matchMaker.Matches(inputPath);
```

In your case you want to identify different characters and trim them, so you'd identify those strings with a Regex expression then carry out your parsing logic.

This link has a list of all the Regex commands:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet